# Xcode Storyboard with multiple UIView in one Viewcontroller not allowing to move items in background view

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

Here is screenshot:
[image]

How can I move buttons and label in background UIView..when I touch UIView in storyboard then it selects front one only. How can do it in storyboard? I just want to drag buttons in nib.

Comment: You can move them with the (Size) Inspector, or else move your view to the top (in the bottom of your list) momentarily.

Comment: I wish drag and drop positionsetup, how to make it top view for a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold down `ctrl` + `alt` + `shift` when clicking on the view in your storyboard or xib. A menu will pop up (See below) showing you what views are under your cursor. Select the view you want to move and you can reposition it with either the arrow keys or the size inspector.

[image: menu screenshot]

Comment: this I can do in side bar also..like in my screenshot. I want way to drag and move buttons..just like in old xib.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to reorder the UI Elements in the Document Outline (on the left in your screenshot) so that the button you would like to move is in front of any background elements which may cover it up. This is done by selecting the button, then dragging it to the bottom most section of the view.
Hopefully this is what you are asking for, cheers!